# Why does glob lstat matching entries?

Tags: linux, perl, glob

Looking into behavior in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16443538/132382), I was surprised to see that perl [`lstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lstat.html)s every path matching a glob pattern:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/{foo,bar,baz}.txt  
$ strace -e trace=lstat perl -E 'say $^V; <dir/b*>' 
v5.10.1
lstat("dir/baz.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("dir/bar.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
```

I see the same behavior on my Linux system with `glob(pattern)` and `<pattern>`, and with later versions of perl.

My expectation was that the globbing would simply opendir/readdir under the hood, and that it would not need to inspect the actual pathnames it was searching.

What is the purpose of this `lstat`?  Does it affect the glob()s return?

Comment: @mpapec, I will update with my expectation when I'm next at a terminal, thanks.

Comment: Just a not: I had to change `lstat` to `lstat64` on my system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This strange behavior has been [noticed before on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=984079). It turns out that `glob` calls `lstat` to support its [`GLOB_MARK`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html#POSIX-FLAGS) flag, which has the effect that:

> Each pathname that is a directory that matches the pattern has a slash appended.

To find out whether a directory entry refers to a subdir, you need to `stat` it. This is apparently done even when the flag is not given.

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering the same thing - *"What is the purpose of this lstat? Does it affect the glob()s return?"*

Within bsd_glob.c glob2() I noticed a g_stat call within an if branch that required the GLOB_MARK flag to be set, I also noticed a call to g_lstat just before that was not guarded by a flag check.  Both are within an if branch for when the end of pattern is reached.
If I remove these 2 lines in the glob2 function in perl-5.12.4/ext/File-Glob/bsd_glob.c

```
- if (g_lstat(pathbuf, &sb, pglob))
-     return(0);
```

the only perl test (make test) that fails is test 5 in ext/File-Glob/t/basic.t with:

```
not ok 5
#   Failed test at ../ext/File-Glob/t/basic.t line 92.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[0] = 'asdfasdf'
#     $expected->[0] = Does not exist
```

Test 5 in t/basic.t is

```
# check nonexistent checks
# should return an empty list
# XXX since errfunc is NULL on win32, this test is not valid there
@a = bsd_glob("asdfasdf", 0);
SKIP: {
    skip $^O, 1 if $^O eq 'MSWin32' || $^O eq 'NetWare';
    is_deeply(\@a, []);
}
```

If I replace the 2 lines removed with:

```
+   if (!((pglob->gl_flags & GLOB_NOCHECK) ||
+         ((pglob->gl_flags & GLOB_NOMAGIC) &&
+          !(pglob->gl_flags & GLOB_MAGCHAR)))){
+     if (g_lstat(pathbuf, &sb, pglob))
+       return(0);
+   }
```

I don't see any failures from "make test" for perl-5.12.4 on linux x86_64 (RHEL6.3 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64) and when using:

```
strace -fe trace=lstat perl -e 'use File::Glob q{:glob};
                               print scalar bsd_glob(q{/var/log/*},GLOB_NOCHECK)'
```

I no longer see the lstat calls for each file in the dir. 
I don't mean to suggest that the perl tests for glob (File-Glob) are comprehensive (they are not), or that a change such as this will not break existing
behaviour (this seems likely).  As far as I can tell the code with this (g_l)stat call existed in original-bsd/lib/libc/gen/glob.c 24 years ago in 1990.

Also see:

- Chapter 6. Benchmarking Perl of "Mastering Perl" By brian d foy, Randal L. Schwartz
  contains a section on comparing code where code using glob() and opendir() is compared.
- "future globs (was "UNIX mindset...")" in comp.unix.wizards from Dick Dunn in 1991.
- Usenet newsgroup mod.sources "'Globbing' library routine (glob)" from Guido van Rossum in July 1986 - I don't see a reference to "stat" in this code.